# VBA special character encoding problem while creating text file

Tags: json, vba, text, encoding

I am currently working on a macro which pulls data from an excel sheet and create a formatted JSON text file.
The problem is my the special characters are displaying wrong in my output file :

```
i expect "â" but i got "\u00E2"
i expect "é" but i got "\u00E9"
...
```

The code :

```
res = ConvertToJson(items, Whitespace:=2)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set outputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(path & "\output_" & CStr(Format((Now()), "ddmmyyyy_hhmmss")) & ".json", False, False)
outputFile.WriteLine res
outputFile.Close
```

I got the encoding errors while using this logic. I tried conversion through NotePad++, changing createTextFile function arguments but I always got those errors.

Has anyone already faced this issue and found a fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used a custom function to replace wrongly encoded characters and it worked like a charm.

```
Function SpecialCharReplace(ByVal strInput As String) As String
    ' Replace accented characters
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C0", "À")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C1", "Á")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C2", "Â")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C3", "Ã")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C4", "Ä")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C5", "Å")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C6", "Æ")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C7", "Ç")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C8", "È")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00C9", "É")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00CA", "Ê")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00CB", "Ë")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00CC", "Ì")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00CD", "Í")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00CE", "Î")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00CF", "Ï")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00D1", "Ñ")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00D2", "Ò")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00D3", "Ó")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00D4", "Ô")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00D5", "Õ")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00D6", "Ö")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00D8", "Ø")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00D9", "Ù")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00DA", "Ú")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00DB", "Û")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00DC", "Ü")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00DD", "Ý")
    
    ' Now lower case accents
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00DF", "ß")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E0", "à")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E1", "á")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E2", "â")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E3", "ã")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E4", "ä")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E5", "å")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E6", "æ")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E7", "ç")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E8", "è")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00E9", "é")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00EA", "ê")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00EB", "ë")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00EC", "ì")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00ED", "í")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00EE", "î")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00EF", "ï")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F0", "ð")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F1", "ñ")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F2", "ò")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F3", "ó")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F4", "ô")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F5", "õ")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F6", "ö")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F8", "ø")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00F9", "ù")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00FA", "ú")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00FB", "û")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00FC", "ü")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00FD", "ý")
    strInput = Replace(strInput, "\u00FF", "ÿ")
    
    SpecialCharReplace = strInput
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use ADODB for that purpose to be able to set encodings.

You would have to set a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.x Library` or use late binding instead.

This sample creates a UTF-8 encoded file and uses CRLF as linefeed, but you can customize it to your needs:

```
Dim path As String
path = "c:\yourPath"

Dim res As String
res = ConvertToJson(items, Whitespace:=2)

With New ADODB.Stream
    .Open
    .Charset = "UTF-8"
    .LineSeparator = ADODB.LineSeparatorEnum.adCRLF
    .WriteText res, ADODB.StreamWriteEnum.adWriteLine
    .SaveToFile path & "\output_" & CStr(Format((Now()), "ddmmyyyy_hhmmss")) & ".json", _
        ADODB.SaveOptionsEnum.adSaveCreateOverWrite
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I will give a try to ADODB.Stream solution and validate if it works

Comment: The file still contains wrong encoding with ADODB.Stream object. It seems that's the problem come from earlier stage of my macro since my "res" variable already contains wrongly encoded characters...

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in a line of code after `res` has been set and then check the content in the immediate window. Maybe you see what is going on. Alternatively set a proper breakpoint in your `ConvertToJson()` when adding these values.